# Implications of pairwise independence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, independence

I'm trying to prove that if $X_1,X_2,X_3 \in \mathbb{R}$ are pairwise independent, then $X_1$ and $(X_2,X_3) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ are independent.

**My attempt**: We know

$$ f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2) = f_{X_1}(x_2)f_{X_2}(x_2) $$
$$ f_{X_1,X_3}(x_1,x_3) = f_{X_1}(x_3)f_{X_2}(x_3) $$
$$ f_{X_2,X_3}(x_2,x_3) = f_{X_2}(x_2)f_{X_3}(x_3) $$

Now we need to show

$$ f_{X_1,(X_2,X_3)}(x_1,(x_2,x_3)) = f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2,X_3}(x_2,x_3) $$

We know

$$f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2,X_3}(x_2,x_3) = f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x_2)f_{X_3}(x_3)$$

I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to prove is not true.

Throw two numbered coins ($1$ and $2$) and let $X_i$ take value $1$ if coin $i$ shows heads and value $0$ otherwise. Further let $X_3$ take value $1$ if $X_1=X_2$ and value $0$ otherwise.

Then pairwise independence for $X_1,X_2,X_3$ is not difficult to verify, but:$$P(X_1=1\wedge (X_2,X_3)=(1,1))=P(X_1=1=X_2)=\frac14$$
while:$$P(X_1=1)P((X_2,X_3)=(1,1))=P(X_1=1)P(X_1=1=X_2)=\frac12\frac14=\frac18$$

So $X_1$ and $(X_2,X_3)$ are not independent.

Comment: What if all three were individually Gaussian?

Comment: If $(X_1,X_2,X_3)^T$ has Gaussian distribution and $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are pairwise  independent then $\mathsf{Cov}(X_1,X_2)=\mathsf{Cov}(X_1,X_3)=\mathsf{Cov}(X_2,X_3)=0$ so that their covariance matrix only has positive values on the diagonal. Then - because their distribution is Gaussian - $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are independent . From that it follows directly that $X_1$ and $(X_2,X_3)^T$ are independent.

Comment: You assumed that $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ is jointly Gaussian. What if they are individually Gaussian? Then does the pairwise independence imply that they're jointly Gaussian? Because I remember reading somewhere that two individual Gaussians may not be jointly Gaussian but if they're independent they will be jointly Gaussian.

Comment: It $X,Y$ are independent then they must be defined on the same probability space hence have a joint distribution that can be found on base of their individual distributions. I they are Gaussian then their joint distribution will also be Gaussian. So if $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are pairwise independent then $(X_1,X_2)$, $(X_1,X_3)$ and $(X_2,X_3)$ have Gaussian distribution. But there is no guarantee (that I can find) that also $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ has Gaussian distribution. That is why I mentioned that as a seperate condition in my former comment.

Comment: If might be a good question to ask: if $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are pairwise independent and each of them has Gaussian distribution then has $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ Gaussian distribution? I suspect not necessarily, but have no real answer to that right now.

Comment: Thank you got it.